# Unity3d Como puedo pasar un vector3[] a VFX graph sin utilizar un ciclo en el main thread de Unity3D? Existe algun nodo que admita?

Tags: unity3d

Estoy experimentando con VFX graph, y me gustaria pasar un arreglo de Vector3[] a un VisualEffect pero no encuentro manera de hacerlo a no ser que haga un ciclo for() en el Update, pero como el array es tan extenso pierdo muchos FPS, alguna idea?